# Netbeans Git Repository

Tags: git, netbeans, repository

I want to push a project from NetBeans to GitHub.

But when I try to create the GitHub Repository:
`team -> Git -> Initialize Repository`.

It does create the repository.

But my classes don't highlight in green showing that they are added. When I right-click on the project it doesn't show the option to `commit`.

Answer (score -1):

1. At the Repository page, specify the path to a Git repository `location`, `user name` and `password` [Save it for future use]
2. Click Next to switch to the next step of the wizard.
3. At the `Remote Branches` page, select the repository `branch(es)` to be fetched to your local repository. `Click Next`.
4. At the Destination `Directory page`, do the following:

   - In the Parent Directory field, the path to the directory intended
     for the cloned local repo (or click the Browse button and navigate to
     the directory).
   - The Parent Directory field is pre-filled with the path to the
     default `NetBeansProjects directory` where all NetBeans projects are
     stored.
   - In the `Clone Name field`, the name of the local folder where the
     original project will be cloned to. By default Clone Name is filled
     out with the actual `Git repository` name.
   - In the `Checkout Branch` field, select the branch to be checked out
     into the working tree.
   - In the `Remote Name field`, the name that represents the original
     repository being cloned. `origin` is the default alias of the
     repository being cloned.
   - Leave the Scan for NetBeans Projects after Clone checkbox selected
     to activate after-scanning right after the clone finishes.
   - `Click Finish`.
     [A Git repository is cloned, the metadata `.git` folder is created inside the folder]

Hope this would work.

**Updated**
[Check this video](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/github_nb_screencast.html)

Comment: This is nothing but a repeat of the standard instructions, and does nothing to address the OP's actual question: Why don't the "added" files show up as green in the NetBeans Projects or Files tree?